# Compare value against two values with 'or' operator

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple `if ()` condition which needs to check if value is either `1` or `2` (for example). Let's say the value we are comparing against is not 'simple':

```
if(it.first().property.value == 1 || it.first().property.value == 2) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Is there a better way to perform this check (without typing the entire expression to get the actual value twice)? The only thing that comes to mind is

```
if(listOf(1, 2).contains(it.first().property.value)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

But I'm afraid it's more memory consuming since it has additional `list` introduced.

Comment: What about `when (it.first().property.value)`? Have you tried that?

Comment: I would really like it to be one-liner since I often use this in .takeIf {} expression which is usually part of an even bigger expression.

Comment: What's the type of `it`?

Comment: Then do what @JakubZalas suggested: Write an extension function and use that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last suggestion is a good one in general, though it's usually better to use a predefined list (and the `in` operator):

```
// At the top level, or in a (companion) object:
val acceptableValues = listOf(1, 2)

// Then in the relevant part of the code:
if (it.first().property.value in acceptableValues)
    // Do stuff
```

That only allocates the list once, and performance is about as good as any other option.  It's also very readable, and general.

(If the list doesn't naturally fit into a named property, you'd have to judge how often it might be needed, in order to trade a minor performance benefit against the conciseness of putting it directly in the condition.)

In fact, because you're looking for consecutive integers, there's a more concise option for this particular test:

```
if (it.first().property.value in 1..2)
    // Do stuff
```

That would work whenever the acceptable values form an (uninterrupted) range.

Alternatively, if you're always checking against exactly two values, you could write a simple extension function:

```
fun <T> T.isEither(a: T, b: T) = this == a || this == b
```

(You could write a more general one using a `vararg` param, but that would create an array each time — very similar to the `in listOf()` case we started with.)

Comment: Great idea with in <Range>. That is all I need for now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool!  But @deHaar's suggestion of a `when` is also worth considering :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can decide it using a `when` expression like in this example:

```
fun main() {
    val number = 22

    when (number) {
        1, 2 -> println("${number} is 1 or 2")
        in 10..20 -> println("${number} is between 10 and 20 (inclusively)")
        else -> println("${number} is either negative, equals 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 21 or any number above")
    }
}
```

The output here is

```
22 is either negative, equals 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 21 or any number above
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define an extension function on the type of `it` to make it more readable:

```kotlin
if(it.isOneOrTwo()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Not sure what's the type of your `it`, replace `TYPEOFIT` accordingly:

```kotlin
private inline fun TYPEOFIT.isOneOrTwo() = first().property.value == 1 || first().property.value == 2
```

To additionally improve the condition you could leverage `when`:

```kotlin
private inline fun TYPEOFIT.isOneOrTwo() = when(first().property.value) {
    1,2 -> true
    else -> false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wont that use even more resources, since a new function is introduced?

Comment: It's micro optimization at best. I'd worry more about readability than a hypothetical overhead, which would be negligible anyway. Have you actually measured the performance? I'd trust the compiler can do its job well and inline the private function. You could actually mark it as inline too.

Comment: @Webfreak inline functions are inlined at the callsite upon compilation.